# fabric delivers crash reports, but no users in answers

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using crashlytics and fabrics since a longer time. But with one update I don't see the users in the answers-section any more. I do get crash reports from that app version, but it doesn't appear in the answers section.

What am I missing here, what could be the reason for this?